# Meteor code not working on ec2

Tags: node.js, meteor, amazon-ec2

i created tar.gz file from my dev meteor project directory which is working on my local machine but the extract of tar.gz is not working on ec2. It showing following error.

```
W20150815-19:56:58.515(0)? (STDERR) 
W20150815-19:56:58.516(0)? (STDERR) /home/ubuntu/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.1.3.1md4rq1++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.linux.x86_64/dev_bundle/server-lib/node_modules/fibers/future.js:245
W20150815-19:56:58.517(0)? (STDERR)                         throw(ex);
W20150815-19:56:58.518(0)? (STDERR)                               ^
W20150815-19:56:58.522(0)? (STDERR) Error: Cannot find module 'elasticsearch'
W20150815-19:56:58.522(0)? (STDERR)     at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:338:15)
W20150815-19:56:58.522(0)? (STDERR)     at Function.Module._load (module.js:280:25)
W20150815-19:56:58.522(0)? (STDERR)     at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
W20150815-19:56:58.522(0)? (STDERR)     at require (module.js:380:17)
W20150815-19:56:58.522(0)? (STDERR)     at Object.Npm.require (/home/ubuntu/snapstall/.meteor/local/build/programs/server/boot.js:130:18)
W20150815-19:56:58.523(0)? (STDERR)     at app/server/elastic.js:1:60
W20150815-19:56:58.523(0)? (STDERR)     at app/server/elastic.js:59:3
W20150815-19:56:58.523(0)? (STDERR)     at /home/ubuntu/snapstall/.meteor/local/build/programs/server/boot.js:222:10
W20150815-19:56:58.523(0)? (STDERR)     at Array.forEach (native)
W20150815-19:56:58.523(0)? (STDERR)     at Function._.each._.forEach (/home/ubuntu/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.1.3.1md4rq1++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.linux.x86_64/dev_bundle/server-lib/node_modules/underscore/underscore.js:79:11)
```

Comment: Have you installed elastic search module on your server?

Comment: yes....npm install -g elasticsearch

Comment: are you running meteor using the same user as when you installed the npm package? also, what happens when you try `require('elasticsearch')` in node?

Comment: have you run `npm install` inside the `server` sub-directory of your bundle?

Comment: @ChristianFritz yes i created a small js file to connect elasticsearch and its working.

Comment: @apendua yes it worked...........Thanks a lot!!

Comment: Cool, so let me turn this into an answer then :)

Comment: remove `.meteor` folder and let meteor install everything again

Answer (score 1):

All npm dependencies of your application are declared inside `package.json` located in your bundle's `programs/server` subdirectory. To make sure they're all resolved you need to run

```
npm install
```

inside that subdirectory after unpacking the archive.

The reason it's not done automatically is both to have a bundle of smaller size and to make sure npm installs binaries (if any) that match your target system architecture, which may not necessarily be the same as the one you're creating the bundle in.